# MYSQL stock entry

Tags: mysql

### PURCHASE TABLE

> id (Primary Key)  ItemNo, ItemName, Units, Qty, Location, CPrice,
>   SPrice, Supplier, PONo

### STOCK TABLE

> id (Primary Key), ItemNo, Qty, Location

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ItemNo, Location FROM stock WHERE stock.ItemNo = 'poitem.ItemNo' AND stock.Location = 'poitem.Location') THEN 
  UPDATE stock SET stock.Qty = stock.Qty + poitem.Qty WHERE stock.ItemNo = 'poitem.ItemNo'; 
ELSE 
   INSERT INTO stock (stock.ItemNo, stock.Qty, stock.Location) SELECT poitem.ItemNo, poitem.Qty, poitem.Location FROM poitem; 
 END If
```

THis is my Code, but its not working as it should be
I need to update stock table when i enter a record through purchase table only is the record already exists, otherwise new record need to be entered.

Example:
ItemNo - Qty - Location
 1001    - - -       15      - - -      A
 1001    - - -       12      - - -      B
 1002    - - -    50        - - -    C
 1003    - - -     12        - - -    A
Can any one please write MYSQL code for this.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this code in a stored program (procedure/function/trigger) ?

Comment: Looks like you are trying SQL-server code in MySQL that doesn't work.. IF EXISTS can't be used at the front in normal SQL.. IF EXISTS at the front can only be used in procedure, function and trigger SQL

Comment: YES, I am using this code inside a procedure

Comment: Replace singe quotes with backtick or lose them entirely. Where does poitem.ItemNo and poitem.location come from?

Comment: Is poitem the same table as purchase in your question?

Comment: (POITEMS TABLE )
id (Primary Key) ItemNo, ItemName, Units, Qty, Location, CPrice, SPrice, Supplier, PONo
(STOCK TABLE)
id (Primary Key) ItemNo, Qty, Location
yes. poitem is the same table as purchase table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if exists will always evaluate to true (unless the stock table is empty) so the update will never happen (unless the stock table is empty). I think a procedure is inappropriate here unless you are calling it for every insert. Even if you are a trigger is probably a better bet.

```
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t after insert on poitems
for each row 
begin
IF EXISTS (SELECT ItemNo, Location FROM stock WHERE stock.ItemNo = new.ItemNo AND stock.Location = new.Location) THEN 
   UPDATE stock SET stock.Qty = stock.Qty + new.Qty WHERE stock.ItemNo = new.ItemNo and stock.Location = new.Location; 
ELSE INSERT INTO stock (ItemNo, Qty, Location)  values(new.ItemNo, new.Qty, new.Location) ; 
END If;
end $$
```

I have also amended your update statement to match the if exists clause and fixed the insert statement and a few other things which looked wrong.

so given

```
drop table if exists poitems,stock;

create  TABLE poitems(id int auto_increment Primary Key, ItemNo int, ItemName varchar(10), Units int, Qty int, Location int, CPrice int
                    , SPrice int, Supplier int, PONo int);

create table stock(id int auto_increment Primary Key ,ItemNo int, Qty int, Location int);

insert into poitems(itemno,qty,location) values (1,1,1),(1,1,1),(2,2,1);
```

results in

```
+----+--------+------+----------+
| id | ItemNo | Qty  | Location |
+----+--------+------+----------+
|  1 |      1 |    2 |        1 |
|  2 |      2 |    2 |        1 |
+----+--------+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Even though  i am getting the following error, its works fine inside php code.
but i dont know why i am getting this message.
------ Failed to execute SQL. Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'create trigger t after insert on poitem for each row begin IF EXISTS (SEL' at line 2 (1064) ------

Comment: I don't think you need to set the delimiters if you are creating from php.

Comment: the above message appears after removing delimiters and with delimiters also it doesnt work.